# Different result in NodeJS calculating MD5 hash using crypo

Tags: node.js, hash, md5

I am trying to get the MD5 has from a number in NodeJS using crypto but I am getting a different hash returned then I get from site where I can calculate the has.

According to http://onlinemd5.com/ the MD5 has for 1092000 is AF118C8D2A0D27A1D49582FDF6339B7C.

When I try to calculate the hash for that number in NodeJS it gives me a different result (ac4d61a5b76c96b00235a124dfd1bfd1). My code:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const num = 1092000;
const hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(toString(num)).digest('hex');
console.log(hash);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you convert it to a string normally it works:

```
const hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(String(num)).digest('hex'); // or num.toString()
```

See the difference:

```
toString(num) = [object Undefined]
(1092000).toString() = "1092000"
```

If you `console.log(this)` in a Node env by default you will see that it is:

```
this = {} typeof = 'object'
```

`this` in a Node env is pointing at `module.exports` so you're calling this [toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) on the `Object.prototype` which is not the right thing to do a string conversion on anything other than `module.exports`.

Comment: That weird toString came up Googling how to convert a number to a string in JavaScript. It actually threw no error so I assumed it was the way it should be done. You answer solved the issue. Thank (need to wait 7 minutes before I can accept it as the answer).